# Limit dependencies from my form generator script

Tags: php, oop

I've made little PHP script, which generates a html form. The script consists of 2 parts, the form and the form elements.

Now when I want a form, I can do this:

```
$form = new Form();
$checkbox = new Checkbox();
$checkbox->setLabel('Label');
$checkbox->setData('data');
$form->addElement($checkbox);
$textarea = new Textarea();
$textarea->setData('data');
$radio = new Radio();
$form->addElement($textarea);
$form->addElement($radio);
```

The thing is, when I have a large form with lots of different elements, my model or controller has a lot of use statements, pointing to the different form elements.

I'm quite new to OOP, but people told me that lots of dependencies are a bad practise.

What is the best approach to limit these dependencies?

Should I make another class which includes all the form dependencies, and use this class to have only 1 dependency, or is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about...

```
class Form
{
    ...
    public function add($element)
    {
        ...

        return $this;
    }
}

class Checkbox extends FormElement
{
    ...
    public function __construct($data = null, $label = null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So now you can:

```
$form = new Form();
$form
    ->add(new Checkbox('data', 'Label'))
    ->add(new Textarea('data'))
    ->add(new Radio('data'));
```

Or you can take a look to the Symfony's form component (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html , https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form , http://webmozarts.com/bsc-thesis.pdf).

The Symfony's approach is to use "tags", string names that represent an instance of a form element (implementing an interface to ensure some methods), so you can change those dependencies by configuration.

Well, it seems you liked it! then you'll have to implement a sort of form manager to get the instances by name, good luck!

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I do like the shorter code this gives me, but this way my controller/model would still have 4 dependencies to the form and elements, am i right? edit: oh thanks for the read, i see they have implemented a solution to my problem!

Comment: Yes, you're right, but since you are trying to separate form elements in different classes (good thing) you can't avoid those dependencies.